# Adding object to a Collection in the first position with backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I have this simple function to add a Folder to a collection called 'Folders'.

```
folderAdded: function(folder) {
            this.folders.add(folder);
            this.$el.empty();
            this.render();
    }
```

By default this will add the object in the first position, so it will appear the first one. As my query is order by created, if I refresh the page, the object will go the first place.

How can I add the object at the **beginning of the collection**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`unshift`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-unshift) method of the collection.

> Add a model at the beginning of a collection. Takes the same options as [add](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add)

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you!

Comment: You can additionally use collection.add(model, { at : 0 })